# Llamar a la tabla de mi base de datos mysql en la funcion de mi controlador en laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-7

Tengo una vista donde quiero actualizar una imagen para articulos, en esta vista llamo a la funcion update_imagen de mi controlador, pero ahi mismo quiero guardar los datos ya actualizados en la base de datos, pero no se como llamar a la tabla (llamada investigacions)

VISTA

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="text-center" action="/imagen" style="color: #000000; margin-left: 105px;" method="POST">
              <label>Actualizar imagen</label>
              <input type="file" name="imagen" >
              <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
              <br>
              <input type="submit" value="Subir" class="pull-left btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="margin-left: -100px;">
        </form>
```

EN LA RUTA

```
Route::post('imagen', 'InvestigacionController@update_imagen');
```

CONTROLADOR

```
public function update_imagen(Request $request)
{
    $investigacion = investigacion::all();

    if($request->hasFile('imagen')){
        $imagen = $request->file('imagen');
        $filename = time() . '.' . 'jpg';
        Image::make($imagen)->resize(300, 300)->save(public_path('/img/articulos/' . $filename) );
        $investigacion = investigacion();
        $investigacion->imagen = $request->$filename;
        $investigacion->save();
    }

    return redirect()->route('investigacion.index');
}
```

Especificamente en la linea de $investigacion = investigacion(); como lo cambiaría???
tengo un codigo similar en el controlador del usuario, pero ahi lo llamo así:

```
 $user = Auth::user();
 $user->avatar = $filename;
 $user->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que quieres cambiar la imagen para todos los registros de la tabla `investigaciones`. `$investigacion` no trae UN registro, sino todos los registros de las investigaciones. Así, super sencillo sería algo dentro del `if` como:

```
$investigaciones = investigacion::all(); // antes del if

if ($request...) {
    ...
    Image::make(...
    ...
    foreach $investigaciones as $investigacion {
        $investigacion->imagen = $request->filename;
        $investigacion->save();
    }
}
```

Claro que eso hace un update por cada registro, que si son pocos, no pasa nada, pero si son mucho, es demasiado ineficiente.

La otra, que sería más eficiente, sería hacerlo a través de `DB`, con un `update` directo a la tabla. Dentro del `if` iría:

```
DB::table('investigaciones')->update(['imagen' => $request->filename]);
```

Y hasta te ahorras el `SELECT` (`investigacion::all()`)

Comment: con el DB::table... me da este error SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'imagen' cannot be null (SQL: update `investigacions` set `imagen` = ?)

Comment: Ese es otro problema, checa que es lo que lleva tu `$request->filename`, es decir si el request está bien armado. Me suena a problema de validación

Comment: hice un dd y tal cual lleva un null...pero si hago un dd($request->imagen); no esta null, que haria en este caso??? ya que lo que quiero que guarde es el filename, no el imagen

Comment: decidi dejar el DB asi: DB::table('investigacions')->update(['imagen' => $filename]); sin el request y si se guarda pero en todos los registros, y solo quiero que se guarde en el que seleccione anteriormente